# Can these spells be cast one after another to create a tunnel?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Suppose there is a 60-foot wide stone obstacle. Going over or around it is not possible.

The wizard then casts, one after the other:

1. [Transmute Rock to Mud](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/transmuteRockToMud.html): use six 10x10 cubes in a straight line.
2. [Change Dust to Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/frog-god-games/change-dust-to-water/): the mud is just wet dirt. The spell affects dirt.
3. [Change Water to Dust](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/frog-god-games/change-water-to-dust/): Now we have a fine, dry dust.
4. [Gust of Wind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gust-of-wind/): The spell description: "It can create a stinging spray of sand or dust."

Comment: "Pardon me, Mr. Wizard, sir? Can I interest you in this [*passwall*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/passwall.html#passwall) spell?"

Comment: @HeyICanChan yes, but passwall doesn't allow a large group through and through.

Comment: Is the earth under this rock also rock, or it is soil? A single cast of [move earth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/move-earth) could allow you to dig a tunnel under your rock.

Comment: Eitherway, Im not convincend by *"mud is just wet dirt"*.

Comment: @shadowkras point made.

Comment: @ShadowKras *move earth* says specifically: "the spell cannot be used for tunneling."

Comment: @DanB not in the sense to build a tunnel in the middle of a rock (*tunneling*), because the spell doesn't create the necessary supports for the tunnel to remain in place. But in the sense that moving the dirt under the rock would make it's foundation to move, because of this tunnel of dirt and the rock would shift positions or slide out of the way, effectively creating a passage.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence given should work, although only steps 1 and 2 should be required, as all of the former rock obstacle is now water, and should flow away.

Depending on the surroundings, The required steps might actually be simpler. If there is an open area adjacent to the obstacle, just casting Transmute Rock to Mud would cause the now-mud object to collapse, and spread out to cover whatever surface is nearby. And of course, the spell only works on natural stone, and can only turn a 10-foot deep section into mud, so a taller obstacle would be unaffected. Move Earth would also allow transport of the now-mud obstacle, if required.

Answer (score 2):

**No, this does not work.**

Transmute Rock to Mud provides you *magical mud* because its duration is Permanent (not Instantaneous) and you could use *dispel magic or transmute mud to rock* spells to return it to its previous form.

However, it does not reference allowing Change Dirt to Water which has the caveat:

> Magical dust or earth cannot be affected by this spell.

Comment: I also thought this would be the case, and even wrote a lenghty answer about it. But this is not magical dirt, its dirt affected by a magical effect.

Comment: I disagree, but I see your point. I consider the dirt you created to be magic because it simply doesn't exist without the magic. If it was an instantaneous spell it would be different because what was rock is now dirt. But in this case, its only dirt as long as its magically altered. I'm not positive that this is RAW, but it seems to fit to me.

Comment: @Ifusao that interpretation would turn any weapon affected by a spell into a magical weapon. For instance, [Disguise Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disguise-weapon).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, they can. But they dont have to.

First, I would refrain from applying real-world physics (*"mud is wet dirt"*) into spells. Spells work best if they are read literally, and magic works best when you don't try to go around corners. This means that if the spell doesn't say it can affect *mud* (or earth as a general term), then it doesn't affect *mud*. Even things like an electricity or fire spell will not behave like their natural elements if the spell doesn't say so (you can throw [fireballs underwater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain/)). And some people wouldn't allow [Control Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/control-water) to affect mud to *evaporate* this water and turn your mud into dust.

A few cases will require GM discretion, and this sounds like one of those.

The only reference to the definition of *dirt* in the rules is the [Move Earth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/move-earth/) spell. Which, even though also being a 6th level spell, has several 
restrictions that prevent it from working to move your obstacle.

> Move earth moves dirt (clay, loam, sand, and soil)

If you look up the definition of these four, you will get many results to things similar to *soft earth*, none of which remotely remind us of *mud*. While the definition of *mud* is **water combined with any type of soil**. [Soften Earth and Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/soften-earth-and-stone/) shows that these things are different and the spell has a different effect for each type of soil, be it mud or dirt. So our *mud* is not merely *dirt* and not a valid target for *Change Dust to Water*, in my opinion.

Either way, [Transmute Rock to Mud](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/transmuteRockToMud.html) has a permanent duration, meaning that this is an ongoing magical effect that could be dispelled at any time. [Dispel Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) could revert the mud back to rock at any time. So, even if the requirements of [Change Dust to Water](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/frog-god-games/change-dust-to-water/) forbid you from using magical dirt, this would not be the case, this is *mundane dirt affected by a magical effect*, and thus, a valid target.

> This spell transforms an area of dust or dirt into wholesome, fresh, drinkable water. **Magical dust or earth cannot be affected by this spell.**

Regardless, only [Transmute Rock to Mud](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/transmuteRockToMud.html) is required if your object is to remove a giant rock out of your way. This is possible due to the examples of the spell being used to affect buildings and structures:

> However, small buildings or structures often rest upon foundations shallow enough to be damaged or even partially toppled by this spell.

The spell affects two 10-feet cubes per caster level, meaning that **you can transmute at least 18 10-feet cubes** per cast (CL 9, minimum to cast the spell). You could easily make this rock slide or roll away by transforming the earth or rock underneath into mud. Depending on the size of this rock, the entire thing could be turned into mud and you would just have to force your way through. Again, [Soften Earth and Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/soften-earth-and-stone/) shows that its possible to force your way through mud.

To make the math easier, we could assume that we stacked these 18 blocks in a form like 9x2, so either the width or the height would be 3 blocks tall/long, and the other would be 2 blocks long/tall ([visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3quxh.png)), which nets us dimensions of about 60x60x20 feet. According to [this calculator](http://fredburrows.com/calculator/calc.html), this volume of common stone should weight about 330 tons. For reference, the largest boulders in [stonehenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge) can weight up to 50 tons, while the small ones are about 2 tons. So you could turn about six of those boulders into mud.

Also, if you need a visual reference of this whole thing, this is what [5 cubic feet of dirt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjCpc.png) looks like, and this is a [stonehenge boulder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfUUe.jpg) next to a person.

Answer (score -2):

**You'd have to ask your DM.**  Several of the details here depend on careful interpretation of vague spell wording; we can describe the issues, but this is the sort of thing that has to come down to a DM ruling.

Your first spell, *transmute rock to mud*, says the "depth" of the mud created cannot exceed 10 feet.  Is that ten feet down?  Or ten feet into the surface of the rock?

Your second spell, *change dust to water*, says it affects "dirt" but does not say that it affects mud.  It also says it doesn't affect "magical" earth.  Is mud covered by this spell at all?  (I'd say yes; this spell is creating water, so presumably it can tolerate having some water already present.)  Does this transmuted mud count as "magical" for this purpose?  (I'd say yes.)

It's not clear why you need to bother casting more spells, because the water should just drain out of the tunnel if you've tunneled it right.  Still:

Your third spell, *change water to dust*, says that it "counters and dispels" *change dust to water*.  That means if you cast it on this water, it undoes your previous spell and now you have six ten-foot cubes full of mud again.  This definitely does not work.

There's also some question of cave-ins here.  If you remove a ten-foot cube of stone, how much of that stone would have been load-bearing?  This doesn't seem to be easily web-searchable, so you'll have to trust your DM here.

---

If you're throwing around sixth-level spells anyway, consider casting *disintegrate* instead.

Comment: Disintegrate will only work on smaller objects (*10-foot cube of nonliving matter*), meaning that he would need at least six casts and it doesnt guarantee that the tunnel wouldn't collapse in case the rock cracks or shifts positions.

Comment: I don't think any of the techniques discussed here are proof against collapsing tunnels...